# What do you say for "junction" or "fork" in a path in terms of direction?

Tags: grammar, direction

For junction I know of 交差点 but is that only for traffic junctions or can it be used generally, say, in a mall when the path splits 3 ways or more in front of you.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be called a 分岐点｛ぶんきてん｝. In addition to physical path splits, it's often used to indicate turning points abstractly (like a turning point in your life etc).

---

EDIT: As [@Flaw](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/542/flaw) mentions, this word may not be the best to describe the situation in casual spoken language. A more casual way you could express this is 分かれ{わかれ}道{みち}. However, even though one could describe using both of those words how to navigate to a ***specific*** location via an intersection/a path split (分岐点/分かれ道を右に行く), it might be better to be more detailed. For example to express turning right at the first intersection in a キ shaped intersection (キ-shaped probably isn't a real word), you might say:

> まっすぐに行って、最初の十字路を右に行く

---

Here's an [excerpt from research done by the Japan Tourism Agency](https://www.mlit.go.jp/common/001284231.pdf):
[image]

And here are some other usages I found:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Would 分岐点 in usual daily conversation be natural? Like say when giving or receiving directions to a place. I ask because it's a research article, and I don't know if the same word is used in a colloquial setting

Comment: Mighty thanks Ringil! That certainly seems more like it. Unlike Kousaten which is just fills Google Images with road junctions. The research article is interesting too!

Comment: @Flaw Good point! I'll add a bit about that.